# What is the key of symbol table?

Tags: c++, c

While generating c/c++ symbol table , when adding a new variable or a function name with its values to symbol table what is the key of that entry? name of the variable or address of the variable?
Then how it detect multiple declaraions for that variable according to the symbol table?

Comment: The short answer is "the key is the name".  The longer answer is "it depends".  I assume you're probably talking about a compiler's symbol table.  Look here for more details: http://arantxa.ii.uam.es/~modonnel/Compilers/04_SymbolTablesI.pdf.  You might also be interested in the classic ["Dragon Book"](http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-Edition/dp/0321486811)

Comment: thank you.Yeah i was talking compiler`s symbol table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is the name, of course. The linker never looks for address.

Duplicated symbols are symbols with external linkage and the same name, so it is easy to check.

Comment: Thank you Very much rodrigo for the quick response.